# when try to download a mp3 ;an error occur "The remote server returned an error: NotFound."

Tags: windows-phone-7

when i down load the two same link like those
 [a link](http://www.yyg3.com/upload/gequ/7216/2011723587811.mp3)! and http://files.sparklingclient.com/099_2010.07.09_WP7_Phones_In_The_Wild.mp3 
they all can be downloded by IE .but when i download  in wp7 the  laster can be downloaded the first show an error ""The remote server returned an error: NotFound."" 
 i don't konw why .is  webURL is not suited for wp7?

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    stringUri = "http://upload16.music.qzone.soso.com/30828161.mp3";
  //stringUri = "http://files.sparklingclient.com/079_2009.08.20_ElementBinding.mp3";
    Uri uri = new Uri(stringUri, UriKind.Absolute);            
    GetMusic(uri);
}
private void GetMusic(Uri uri)
{
    request = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
    request.Method = "Post";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";            
    string header= request.Accept;
    request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetAsynResult),request);

}
void GetAsynResult(IAsyncResult result)
{           

    HttpWebResponse reponse = request.EndGetResponse(result) as HttpWebResponse;
    if (reponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {

       Stream stream=reponse.GetResponseStream();
       SaveMusic(stream, "music");
       ReadMusic("music");
       Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
           () =>
           {
               me.AutoPlay = true;
               me.Volume = 100;
               songStream.Position = 0;
               me.SetSource(songStream);
               me.Play();
          });

    }        
}
protected void SaveMusic(Stream stream,string name)
{

            IsolatedStorageFile fileStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            if (!fileStorage.DirectoryExists("Source/Music"))
            {
                fileStorage.CreateDirectory("Source/Music");
            }
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication().OpenFile("Source\\Music\\" + name + ".mp3", FileMode.Create))
            {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
                stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                fileStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                fileStream.Flush();
            }

}
protected void ReadMusic(string name)
{

        using (IsolatedStorageFile fileStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            songStream = null;
            songStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Source\\Music\\" + name + ".mp3", FileMode.Open, fileStorage);                  

        }

}
```

Comment: You should stop using Google Translate for your questions.

Comment: thanks for yor advice ,next time i will use bing translator;or you can help me

Answer (score 1):

Please try to change

```
request.Method = "Post"
```

to

```
request.Method = "Get"
```

Comment: +1 Well spotted! It should actually be `GET` (uppercase), though, for compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running into this problem on the emulator, have you tried running [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)? It will intercept the HTTP requests and you can see if the call being made to the server is the one you expect.

**Remember to close/reopen the emulator after you start Fiddler so that it will pick up the proxy.**

The `NotFound` response can also occur with bad SSL certificates. That doesn't appear to be related to your problem, but something to keep in mind.